# How to move passwords away from docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, security, docker-compose, passwords

Some of the Docker images that I want to build using `docker-compose` require a password to be specified there. But I don't want to store passwords in such a public file. The two cases that I'm facing now are with Redis and Graylog.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6.0.10-alpine
    command: redis-server --requirepass PASSWORD --appendonly yes
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
graylog:
    image: graylog/graylog:4.0
    environment:
      - GRAYLOG_PASSWORD_SECRET=somepasswordpepper
      # Password: admin
      - GRAYLOG_ROOT_PASSWORD_SHA2=8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918
      - GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI=http://127.0.0.1:9000/
    links:
      - mongo
      - elasticsearch
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongo
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 12201:12201
```

How I can store securely this sensitive data and use it in the `docker-compose.yml` file? Via environment variables or in a separate file?

Comment: Have you read https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the following approach:

1.) Externalize your sensitive environment settings with [env_file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env_file-configuration-option):

```
graylog:
    image: graylog/graylog:4.0
    env_file:
      - ./graylog.secrets.env
```

2.) Encrypt the secrets files before checking them into your source repository with a tools like [SOPS](https://github.com/mozilla/sops).

Comment: Would you manually decrypt the .env? AFAIK docker compose doesn't support SOPS